# Сравнение всех элементов в двух списках

Tags: python, list, список

Есть два списка. Нужно сравнить все элементы в обоих списках, те элементы, которые есть в первом списке, но нет во втором списке записать с третий список.

```
list1 = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
list2 = [11, 33, 55]
```

На выходе должен получиться `list3`:

```
[22, 44]
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 3):

можно так с помощью `Counter` из `collections`

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
list2 = [11, 33, 55]
test = list1 + list2
c = Counter(test)
list3 = [x for x in test if c[x] == 1]


print(list3)
```

или в одну строчку

```
result=list(set(list1) - set(list2))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
list2 = [11, 33, 55]

list3 = [i for i in list1 if i not in list2]

print(list3)
[22, 44]
```

ps [list comprehensions](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/08_python_basic_examples/x_comprehensions.html#list-comprehensions)